# Как сделать перенос данных с одной таблицы в другую?

Tags: mysql, sql

Подскажите, каким  запросом  перенести данные с одной таблицы в другую?

Две таблицы полностью идентичны, но записи с теми же ключами в целевой таблице могут уже присутствовать. Структура обоих таблиц:

```
dle_post (id int primary key, col1, col2, ...)
```

Нужно перенести записи в таблице `dle_post` в таблицу `dlew_post`.

Так получаю ошибку:

```
insert into dlew_post select * from dle_post
```

> #1062 - Дублирующаяся запись '50' по ключу 'PRIMARY'

Comment: `insert into table1  select * from table2`

Comment: так может стоит описывать проблему целиком, а не просто "как перенести". добавлю я в этот запрос джойн чтоб исключить совпадения ключей, а вы напишите, что совпадения надо проапдейтить, а не игнорировать. Сформулируйте нормально что есть, что надо сделать и что в результате хотите получить

Answer (score 2):

С [IGNORE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) дубликаты по ключу будут проигнорированы:

> Specify `IGNORE` to ignore rows that would cause duplicate-key violations.

Поэтому, сделайте вот так (на [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ceae375d384df2478916d832eb690734)):

```
insert ignore into dlew_post 
    select * from dle_post;
```